# SQL Temporary Table Title different from original

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a stored procedure which I want to store the results of it in a "temporary table"

I named the table

```
#SalesDiff
```

HOWEVER, 
the title of table under temporary tables folder is shown as

```
#SalesDiff___________________________________________________________00000000023F
```

Below is basic query format

```
SELECT * INTO #SalesDiff FROM (
SELECT A, B, C
     FROM
(.... ) D
```

Comment: yes this is normal. It is done behind the scenes to disambiguate  the possibility of tables with the same name in different sessions. do you have a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporary tables only exist for the lifespan of the connection that creates them. When the SQL engine creates your table for you, it appends information to the end to distinguish *your* version of `#SalesDiff` from the version generated by the other three users running the same stored procedure.

Within your connection, the engine keeps track of the version information automagically, so you don't need to worry about the extension.